# Can I count the number of nodes that are connected to other nodes via specific paths?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi I have `Post` nodes and there can be replies to these `Post`s via `REPLY_TO` relationships.

Like this:
`MATCH (p2:Post)-[r:REPLY_TO]->(p:Post)`

What I'm trying to do is calculate how many total replies there are, and currently the max depth for this is 4 nested replies and there can be many replies to the same post, e.g:

`Post5 -[]-> Post4 -[]-> Post3 -[]-> Post2 -[]-> Post1`

`Post7 -[]-> Post6 -[]-> Post2 -[]-> Post1`

`Post8 -[]-> Post1`

I can't figure out how to count All posts that are replies to one post. Any idea? I started with this and tried changing `count` to `size` and using `collect`, I just cannot figure out what I need to be looking for here!

```
WITH collect(p2) as post2_count, p2
MATCH (p3:Post)-[r3:REPLY_TO]->(p2)
WITH collect(p3) as post3_count, p3, post2_count
RETURN p2_count, count(post3_count)
```

The above is only 2 layers deep, but it didn't work there so I didn't expand to 4.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For things like this, you can use [pattern comprehensions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension). BTW is a great example of why graph databases are so useful since they allow for looking for paths of variable length!

For this graph

[image]

which can be created using this cypher:

```
CREATE (_241:`Post` { `name`: 'A' }) CREATE (_242:`Post` { `name`: 'B' }) CREATE (_243:`Post` { `name`: 'C' }) CREATE (_244:`Post` { `name`: 'D' }) CREATE (_245:`Post` { `name`: 'E' }) CREATE (_242)-[:`REPLY_TO` {}]->(_241) CREATE (_243)-[:`REPLY_TO` {}]->(_242) CREATE (_244)-[:`REPLY_TO` {}]->(_242) CREATE (_245)-[:`REPLY_TO` {}]->(_244)
```

this query returns all the (in)direct replies(yes short and simple):

```
MATCH (p:Post)
RETURN p.name as post,    
       SIZE([(p)<-[:REPLY_TO*]-(reply:Post) | reply]) AS replies
```

returns this result:

```
╒══════╤═════════╕
│"post"│"replies"│
╞══════╪═════════╡
│"A"   │4        │
├──────┼─────────┤
│"B"   │3        │
├──────┼─────────┤
│"C"   │0        │
├──────┼─────────┤
│"D"   │1        │
├──────┼─────────┤
│"E"   │0        │
└──────┴─────────┘
```

if you just want the direct responses:

```
MATCH (p:Post)
RETURN p.name as post,    
       SIZE([(p)<-[:REPLY_TO]-(reply:Post) | reply ]) AS replies
```

you just remove the variable length indicator `*`

```
╒══════╤═════════╕
│"post"│"replies"│
╞══════╪═════════╡
│"A"   │1        │
├──────┼─────────┤
│"B"   │2        │
├──────┼─────────┤
│"C"   │0        │
├──────┼─────────┤
│"D"   │1        │
├──────┼─────────┤
│"E"   │0        │
└──────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: Wow that worked immediately, thank you so much for walking me through it and providing both answers (I ended up using both)! Have a great day and happy holidays!

Comment: @DanFein   good to hear. please accept the answer ;)